# SQL sum if style query

Tags: sql, sum, case

[image]

I have a data set that includes FillQty, Fill price, Bid and Ask.

I am trying to write a query that will look for executions where the fill Price is in-between the Bid and the Ask. If the the fill price is in between, I would like to add FillQty for all of the rows where this condition is met and call it PIQty. For the below data, my PIQty would be 2100 shares.

What would this sql query look like?

```
FillQty FillPrice   Bid Ask PiQTY
100 71.32       71.3    71.32   0
150 16.37       16.36   16.37   0
600 30.085      30.08   30.09   600
500 59.365      59.36   59.37   500
500 28.35       28.34   28.35   0
500 93.04       93.04   93.05   0
500 99.385      79.38   100 500
500 75      71.85   80.1    500
3350                    2100
```

Comment: I'm speculating that you want a SQL query.  You should tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Yes.  Thank you. Updated

Comment: I have a suspicion that this is a homework question... Even if its not, this seems like your asking someone to 'catch you a fish' instead of teaching you to fish. You should follow some SQL tutorials on w3 schools. What you are looking for is a case statement like this: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_case.asp

Comment: You still have not named the database.

Answer (score 0):

This update statement would do, include the table name instead of TABLE

UPDATE TABLE SET PIQTY = FILLQTY
WHERE FILLPRICE>=BID AND FILLPRICE<=ASK

After the update, to get the total of PIQTY run this

SELECT SUM(PIQTY) from TABLE

To get the sum without updating try this, I think the syntax is correct couldnt check

SELECT SUM(FILLQTY) 
FROM(SELECT FILLQTY FROM TABLE
WHERE FILLPRICE>=BID AND FILLPRICE<=ASK)a

Comment: Thank you but I am not trying to write and update this table. I am just trying to return the results without updating. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you try now yes it’s possible

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below.

SELECT FillQty
       , FillPrice
       , Bid
       , Ask
       , CASE WHEN FillPrice > Bid AND FillPrice < Ask AND ELSE 0 END AS PiQTY
FROM   TABLE;

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward SELECT with SUM()

```
SELECT *, SUM(fillQty) as PiQTY
FROM table1
WHERE fillPrice BETWEEN bid AND ask
```